Unexpected end of JSON input error during SignIn in React app when deployed
I'm working on a React app that includes a SignIn component. Everything works fine when I run the app locally, but when I deploy it, I encounter the following error when trying to sign in
There is also an openai chatbot function that is able to request and receive the data. I'm not sure why it seems as if part of the backend is functioning but the rest isn't.
    SignIn.js:39 Error occurred: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at onClick (SignIn.js:29:45)
    onClick @ SignIn.js:39
    await in onClick (async)
    Le @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
    \_e @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:55
    Ir @ react-dom.production.min.js:105
    Br @ react-dom.production.min.js:106
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:117
    uu @ react-dom.production.min.js:273
    Re @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
    Wr @ react-dom.production.min.js:109
    Xt @ react-dom.production.min.js:74
    Qt @ react-dom.production.min.js:73
    Here's the relevant part of my SignIn component:

//this bit does the api call and it all works locally.
        import React, { useState } from "react";
        import NavBar from "../components/Navbar";
        import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

        const API_BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL;

        const LoginPage = () =\> {
        const \[username, setUsername\] = useState("");
        const \[password, setPassword\] = useState("");
        const navigate = useNavigate();

        const handleLogin = async () =\> {
        try {
        const loginData = {
        username,
        password,
        };

            console.log('Sending login data:', loginData);
            
            const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/users/signin`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
            });
            
            const text = await response.text();
            console.log(text);
            
            try {
                const responseData = JSON.parse(text);
            
                if (response.ok) {
                const userId = responseData.data.user.Id;
                navigate(`/${userId}/dashboard`);
                } else {
                console.error("Login failed");
                }
            } catch (jsonError) {
                console.error("Failed to parse JSON response:", jsonError);
            }
            } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error occurred:", error);
            }

        };

//this bit displays the log in page
        return (
        \<div\>
        \<NavBar /\>

            <div style={{ minHeight: '100vh', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#f7fafc' }}>
                <button style={{ color: '#064e3b', fontSize: '2rem', fontWeight: '600', marginTop: '1.25rem', marginLeft: '2.5rem', textDecoration: 'underline', position: 'absolute', top: '0', left: '0' }}>
                Back
                </button>
                <div style={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: '28rem', padding: '2rem', backgroundColor: '#fff', boxShadow: '0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', borderRadius: '0.5rem' }}>
                <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: '600', fontSize: '2.25rem', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                    Let's get Investing!
                </h1>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '1.5rem' }}>
                    <input
                    style={{ width: '100%', padding: '0.5rem 1rem', border: '1px solid #d1d5db', borderRadius: '0.5rem', outline: 'none', focusRing: '2px solid #3b82f6' }}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Username"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}``your text``
                    />
                    <input
                    style={{ width: '100%', padding: '0.5rem 1rem', border: '1px solid #d1d5db', borderRadius: '0.5rem', outline: 'none', focusRing: '2px solid #3b82f6' }}
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button
                    style={{ width: '100%', padding: '0.5rem 1rem', backgroundColor: '#6d28d9', color: '#fff', borderRadius: '0.5rem', fontWeight: '600', fontSize: '1.25rem' }}
                    onClick={handleLogin}
                    >
                    Login
                    </button>
                </div>
                <p style={{ marginTop: '1rem', textAlign: 'center', color: '#4b5563' }}>
                    Don’t have an account?{" "}
                    <Link to="/signup" style={{ color: '#3b82f6', textDecoration: 'underline' }}>
                    Sign up here
                    </Link>.
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        );
        };

        export default LoginPage;

Verified that the API_BASE_URL is correct and pointing to the right server.
Used Postman to check that the backend endpoint works and returns the correct data when accessed directly.
Confirmed that CORS is properly configured on the backend
